# Eclipse - Creation of element failed. Reason : MS950

Tags: eclipse

In **Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers,**
A window pops up when I create a new source file in a C++ project,
(*No matter what Project type or Toolchain is used)

**"Creation of element failed."

"Reason : MS950"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `MS950` is a charset (file encoding).

Make sure you run Eclipse using a full SDK, not only a JRE. The JRE only contains a subset of charsets (only those which most people need). The SDK contains all charsets supported by Java.

Alternatively, convert all text files (and only those) from `MS950` to `UTF-8` and then change the project encoding in Eclipse to `UTF-8` as well.